# Running one make target before another

Tags: go, makefile

I have two make targets, the first compiles my Go application into a binary and then want to use the second to run the binary whilst passing in some arguments. It looks like the following:

```
PATH ?=

build:
    @go build -o huski-go -ldflags="-X 'main.Version=${VERSION}'"

run-node: build
    ./huski-go run -s ${PATH}
```

When I try and run `make run-node PATH="somePath"` from my command line I get the following error

```
/bin/sh: go: command not found
make: *** [build] Error 127
```

The targets work if I run them individually, can anyone see where I am going wrong here?

Comment: What is the purpose of `PATH ?=`?  You want to set it to nothing if it's already not set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PATH is the standard search path to find commands. You seem to set it to something not containing the `go` command.

Use some other variable name like `MYPATH`.